# Problema com Charset entre Asp.Net MVC com Entity Framework e SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou com um problema que todos os valores que vem do banco `SQL Server`, estão com problema de acentuação.

Quando são palavras escritas diretas no `HTML`, não da este problema. O que é estranho é que as palavras são escritas corretamente no banco, sem nenhum problema na acentuação, o problema está na hora de apresentar em tela esses valores, exemplo:

[image: Exemplo]

A palavra certa seria José, e olhe como está no banco de dados:

[image: Exemplo]

Eu já tentei definir o `globalization` no `web.config`, assim:

```
<globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" responseEncoding="iso-8859-1" fileEncoding="iso-8859-1" />
```

Mais não deu certo.

EDIT:

Os valores estão corretos quando carregados na Controller, veja os exemplos respectivos em Banco, Controller e View:

Banco:

[image: Banco]

Controller:

[image: Controller]

View:

[image: View]

Comment: Quando você debuga, dentro da classe está correta a informação? Poste a sua view.

Comment: Veja se dentro do seu `<head>` tem o `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

Comment: @MarlonTiedt vou postar...

Comment: @PabloVargas como eu disse, os textos escritos em HTML puro não estão com este problema, e sim o charset está definido.

Comment: Coloque um break point no retorno do banco e veja como está retornando.

Comment: @MarlonTiedt post editado com os valores respectivos...

Comment: @PabloVargas está no post principal...foi editado.

Comment: Poste o código de sua View por favor.

Comment: @Bruno Já tentou adicionar o que o pablo adicionou nos comentarios ?

Comment: @Bruno precisamos do código da View e não o que ela mostra, abre o arquivo cshtml copia e cola o código na pergunta.

Comment: @Marconi já sim.

Comment: @Bruno, pega o código da view inteira...

Answer (score 0):

Isto aqui está errado:

```
<globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" responseEncoding="iso-8859-1" fileEncoding="iso-8859-1" />
```

O padrão do ASP.NET MVC é a codificação UTF-8. Não há qualquer motivo para usar `ISO-8859-1`, que é mais limitada.

Troque para:

```
<globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Ou ainda, simplesmente remova `requestEncoding`, `responseEncoding` e `fileEncoding`.

Comment: meu caso é semelhante. Porém, está corrigindo uma parte e afetando a outra que já estava correta. Tem alguma ideia ?